# Is the apple app store review process faster for updates than new apps?

Tags: iphone, app-store

wondering if the Apple app store review process is faster for updates than it is for a new app. If we want to be in the store by a certain date with a set of features, does it make sense to send in the app for review with a subset of features, then send an update when it's done?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, yes, the process for reviewing an update is much faster.

Getting an update approved generally takes anywhere from 30 minutes to 2 weeks, while the approval process for a new application generally takes between 2 to 4 weeks, minimum.

That having been said, posting your application to the store with a subset of features may not be any quicker to review than the full application. Apple doesn't check every nook and cranny.

*Though in my opinion,* the focus of your application's launch should not be on how long the review process will take. It's a grab bag, big application or small. Focus instead on **how you want the launch to go.** Some people like a plethora of 1.0.0 features, others like to see big content updates. Take that into consideration.

**Edit:** My original data point was from an application submitted early 2011. I just had another application (Mac) approved for v1.0, and it took approximately 5 days, so the first-time speed seems to have improved significantly.

Comment: Hmm, one for, one against faster updates.  I guess I need a third opinion for a tie-breaker :)  Thanks for response.

Comment: i know it is an old thread, but getting your app reviewed doesn't have to take that long. it was only 4 days in my case. not sure about updates yet, 3 days so far:)

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, for us it seemed that updating was very marginally faster (2-3 days for updates), 5 days for initial review.  Noting that a data point does not a rule make.

Answer (score 1):

Noone knows what really goes on behind that curtain. But in my personal experience, no, that won't help.

It seems as if the bottleneck is getting a reviewers eyes on your app, and the actual review (in most cases) goes quickly.

Lets say you app spends 7 days waiting for review. If an approval takes 1 day in review for an update, or 2 days in review for a new app, it won't make a huge difference in your timeline.